# Laravel 5.3 Composer is not updating package dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.3

I am in the process in developing my first package. The package is working.

Now I want to use Laravels Collective's HTML in my package (dependencies).

**Therefor I added this to the package's composer file:**

(this composer.json is in the root of the package: /packages/vendor/package)

```
{
  "name": "vendor/package",
  "description": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "firstname lastname",
      "email": "info@domain.nl"
    }
  ],
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "require": {
    "twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.3.*"
  }
}
```

I've included the package in Laravel's own composer.json:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Vendor\\Package\\": "packages/vendor/package/src"
    }
},
...
```

When I do composer update the dependencies of the package are not updated. What am I missing here?

Comment: Print the `composer update` output here?

Comment: Also, the contents of the vendor folder?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a local composer repository if your package is not uploaded to [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/) yet. Inside Laravels' application `composer.json` add a local repository like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "/full/or/relative/path/to/development/my-package"
    }
],
"require": {
    "my-package": "*"
}
```

You have to define the package `src` directory inside the package `composer.json` and not inside the Laravels' own `composer.json`. Try and define it like this inside packages' `composer.json`:

```
"require" : {
    "twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.3.*"
},
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "PackageNamespace\\PackageClass\\" : "src/"
    }
},
```

---

**UPDATE**

In order to do a proper package development, you have to keep your package files at some directory other than `/vendor/` composer directory. The main reason is that the developer can delete the entire `/vendor` directory if there might be conflict problems or for cleaning up and setting up everything under composer `/vendor` path. I use a very simple method and I keep my own packages at:

```
<application>/dev/packages/<package-namespace>/<package-name>
```

You have to initialize a git at your package for composer to recognize the repository. To make a git package, go at your package location and run the following commands:

```
cd <application>/dev/packages/<package-namespace>/<package-name>
git init
git add *
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

You may also have to set the `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` before commit, for the git to be able to recognize someone and allow the local commits:

```
git config user.email "you@example.com"
git config user.name "Your Name"
```

In my example, the namespace is `lytr` and the package name is `testpkg`.

The `<application>/dev/packages/<package-namespace>/<package-name>/composer.json` (`<application>/dev/packages/lytr/testpkg`) will look like this:

```
{
    "name" : "lytr/testpkg",
    "description" : "Test package of Lytr",
    "keywords" : [
        "test",
        "package"
    ],
    "license" : "MIT",
    "require" : {
        "twbs/bootstrap" : "dev-master",
        "laravelcollective/html" : "5.3.*"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-0" : {
            "Lytr\\TestPkg\\" : "src"
        }
    },
    "extra" : {
        "branch-alias" : {
            "dev-master" : "1.0-dev"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability" : "dev"
}
```

Then at your application `<application>/composer.json` you'll have a local git repository and your package like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "<full-application-path>/dev/packages/lytr/testpkg"
    }
],
"require" : {
    "lytr/testpkg": "*"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

I include `"minimum-stability": "dev",` because we are using `master-dev` versions. Then after running the `composer update` command **only** having the `"twbs/bootstrap" : "dev-master",` at the package requirements, we'll see the following output on the console window:

[image: Composer update]

And after we change the package `composer.json` and require the `"laravelcollective/html" : "5.3.*",`, we do a `composer update` and we see composer installs the `laravelcollective/html` package properly:

[image: Composer update]

I know this might look confusing and somehow overkill, but this is a proper way for developing packages for composer. You can also have your packages at a git repository and make composer clone that repository instead of your local files. When you're done developing the package and you release it under https://packagist.org/, then you will just have to require your package as any other normal package without the repositories and all the local git thing. Remember, you are at development phase of your package and not at production.

Comment: Do I understand it right that this installs my own package from a local path into my Laravel application? If so, I don't want to do that because I am still developing the package. What I want is to include the packages dependencies.

Comment: @klaaz So, where are your package files located? At some *git* repository or maybe https://packagist.org/ or at your local machine?

Comment: @klaaz that is exactly what you need when you are still developing a package, to have a local package repository, make changes add new features and make it work like you want. When you finish your package, then you upload it at https://packagist.org/ and you require it inside application `composer.json` like any other normal package. See my updated answer for a proper package development method.